# JBoss newbie can't load app to custom port

Tags: binding, jboss, ports

Thanks in advance for your patience.  I'm a recent "convert" to JBoss, having the maintenance of an application thrust upon me, and so long as we don't touch it, it works just fine.  However, the mandate has come down to port the app from Solaris to Linux Fedora, using version 4.2.3GA.

I am using the jboss-port-bindings.xml to specify the ports I want to use, but when I bring JBoss up it loads to standard port 8080 rather than 40029 like I specify in the file.  I have triple-checked the configuration and it's set up on the Linux box exactly the way it's set up on the Solaris box - all the required files are where they are supposed to be, etc.

Anybody have an idea as to why I can't use the specified ports?  If you need more information than what I have supplied, please just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem.  The jboss-service.xml file we had in the server/default/conf folder was correct, but we also needed to add the same file to the server/*appname*/config file, where appname is the name of our application.  This told the app where to go looking for the jboss-port-bindings.xml file and now everybody's happy.

Don't know why we didn't have to have that configuration under Solaris, but anyway, this solved the problem.  Thanks to those who had a look at the question.  Chalk this one up to experience.

Comment: JBoss came with different profile, you need to update only the profile you are running.  (As best practice, make you own JBoss distribution with only the used profile so no update to the wrong one possible...)